# How to make SNMP query in Windows?

Tags: java, windows, snmp

Since I am a noob about SNMP I will have a little question for you. I have written a program in Java to make SNMP queries or normal command line operations etc. I have implemented all connections and functions but as I know I need something secial installed in my PC or something else to make a SNMP query. Can you please tell me what should I have , what should I use to make a SNMP query

Thank you all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if your problem is actually making the SNMP queries from Java, or that you want something on your PC to query for information.

If you want to make SNMP queries from Java, then you will want to use an SNMP library such as http://www.snmp4j.org/. That will allow you to make SNMP queries out to SNMP enabled equipment.

If you want to configure your Windows machine to respond to SNMP queries, then best refer to the document at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726987.aspx which gives an introduction and instructions for configuring on Windows 2003 Server / Windows XP. There is also a link for later operating systems if you are using those.

Comment: No problem. By the way, I've noticed that you aren't accepting answers to your questions (see http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask towards the end). It would be great if you could do this as it generally helps the community as well as the individuals that answer your questions.